# amsmath in combination with tgheros breaks \big delimiters

Tags: fonts, amsmath, delimiters, helvetica

Short background information: I (sadly `;-)`) must use Helvetica fonts, so I'm loading the `tgheros` package and replacing math symbols by the corresponding glyphs in Helvetica. For the delimiters I thought to use `\DeclareMathDelimiter` in order to take the "normal" sized version from Helvetica and the bigger variants from CM. This MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[scale]{tgheros}
% \usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareSymbolFont{sfmathup}{OT1}{qhv}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{(}{\mathopen}{sfmathup}{"28}{largesymbols}{"00}

\begin{document}

\setbox0=\hbox{$\{$} \the\wd0: \box0

\setbox0=\hbox{$\bigl\{$} \the\wd0: \box0

\end{document}
```

produces the following output:

[image: without amsmath]

(Disclaimer: actually I'm also using sans-serif `largesymbols` but this is irrelevant for the problem here.) However, if I un-comment `amsmath` I get

[image: with amsmath]

What is really startling me is that redefining the *parenthesis* is somewhat influencing the *brace*. I *do* remember issues with scaling delimiters and `amsmath` but I couldn't find any idea.

BTW this happens only when `tgheros` is loaded with the `scale` option but I kind of need it, so removing it is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `amsmath` uses `(` for building a box around which to use `\left` and `\right` and produce the `\big` delimiter. However, the `(` in the font you are setting up is too small and it is insufficient for making `\big` to step up a size.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[scale]{tgheros}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareSymbolFont{sfmathup}{OT1}{qhv}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{(}{\mathopen}{sfmathup}{"28}{largesymbols}{"00}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\big}{\bBigg@{1.1}} % originally it's 1
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\{\big\{\Big\{\bigg\{\Bigg\{$

$(\big(\Big(\bigg(\Bigg($

\end{document}
```

Note that `\bigl`, `\bigr` and `\bigm` are based on `\big`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This works....  You can stick in whatever other math font you want.

[image]

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec,unicode-math}
\usepackage[scale]{tgheros}
% \usepackage{amsmath}
\setmathfont[version=termes]{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\mathversion{termes}


\begin{document}

    \setbox0=\hbox{$\{$} \the\wd0: \box0

    \setbox0=\hbox{$\bigl\{$} \the\wd0: \box0

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, but I hope you won't mind if I keep it as a last resort. I could never get the hots for Xe-/LuaLaTeX `;-)`. I should've mentioned it in the question, sorry.

Comment: With lualatex you don't really have to change anything....