# \biggg with NewTX

Tags: newtxmath, bigdelim

I wish to get larger parens than `\Biggl(\Biggr)` with NewTX fonts.  However, following https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/387592 and feeding `pdflatex` with

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[slantedGreek,subscriptcorrection]{newtxmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\biggg}{\bBigg@\thr@@}
\newcommand{\Biggg}{\bBigg@{3.5}}
\def\bigggl{\mathopen\biggg}
\def\bigggm{\mathrel\biggg}
\def\bigggr{\mathclose\biggg}
\def\Bigggl{\mathopen\Biggg}
\def\Bigggm{\mathrel\Biggg}
\def\Bigggr{\mathclose\Biggg}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\(\bigggl(\Biggl(\biggl(\Bigl(\bigl(()\bigr)\Bigr)\biggr)\Biggr)\bigggr)\)
\end{document}
```

we get

[image: output]

As you see, there is no difference between `\bigggl(` and `\Biggl(`, and there is no difference between `\Biggr)` and `\bigggr)`.  The parens do not get larger.  **Why?**  What to do?

Comment: Try `{3.5}` instead of `thr@@` and `{4}` instead of `{3.5}`.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\makeatletter
\def\biggg{\bBigg@{3.5}} % I changed \thr@@ to {3.5}
\def\Biggg{\bBigg@{4}}   % I changed {3.5} to {4}
\makeatother
\def\bigggl{\mathopen\biggg}
\def\bigggm{\mathrel\biggg}
\def\bigggr{\mathclose\biggg}
\def\Bigggl{\mathopen\Biggg}
\def\Bigggm{\mathrel\Biggg}
\def\Bigggr{\mathclose\Biggg}

\begin{document}

\(
\Bigggl(\bigggl(\Biggl(\biggl(\Bigl(\bigl((
)\bigr)\Bigr)\biggr)\Biggr)\bigggr)\Bigggr)
\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thx, got it. Even `\newcommand{\biggg}{\bBigg@{3.07766}}` and `\newcommand{\Biggg}{\bBigg@{3.56997}}` would do. However, why does this happen in first place? Given that the constants `\@ne`, `1.5`, `\tw@`, and `2.5` are used in amsmath.sty to define `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg`, and `\Bigg`, shouldn't the next constant to be used be `\thr@@`?

Comment: After all, `\thr@@` for `\biggg` and `3.5` for `\Biggg` work for standard Computer Modern. They also work with lualatex and TeX Gyre Termes (Math).

Comment: @GeekestGeek Internally, the various `\big` macros use `\left` and `\right`, which in turn choose which delimiter to use based on the font's size and parameters. Clearly, for `newtx` a vertical span of 3.5 (in units of `\big@size`, which itself is based on the size of `\Mathstrutbox@`) isn't enough to trigger the larger size. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/385914/82917 for a similar issue with `tgheros`.